# JavaScript multiple alert promt

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I have read about javascript function hoisitng. But in this case, i did not understood how anonymous functions are getting hoisted

```
var myObj = {
    name: 'MyName',
    dob: 10,
    office: 'MyOffice',
    myFun: function(){
        alert("Anonymous function");
    },
    showItem: function(){
        alert("Name : " + this.name + " office : " + this.office);
    }
};

alert(myObj.showItem());
```

If i run the code, two alert messages prompts. One shows the name, office and other undefined.

Answer (score 3):

That's because two alerts are being called.
The first is in showItem function in your var.
The second is the wrapper alert of

```
alert(myObj.shwItem());
```

Try:

```
myObj.showItem();
```

In this case only the alert from within your defined var will be called.

Answer (score 1):

The alert with the name and office comes from the `showItem` function itself, the `alert(myObj.showItem());` shows undefined because it is alerting what is returned from `showItem`, which is nothing, therefore undefined.